# Set max wall clock time for PHP script execution on Apache (in non-Windows OSes)

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I would like to set a wall clock time limit on execution of PHP scripts on my Apache server.

Unfortunately, [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and the [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) directive set limits on execution time, not wall clock time, as described in the former's documentation:

> #### Note:
>
> The **set_time_limit()** function and the configuration directive [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

However, in general I care about wall clock time, not execution time. Of course, ideally neither limit would ever come into play - but if a script, say, stalls on a deadlocked database query, web request, or file system write for 30 seconds, I want it to die. The fact that the time isn't being spent on actual computation by PHP is irrelevant to me. In fact, I struggle to imagine any situation at all in which an execution time limit would be preferable to a wall-clock time limit (but perhaps I just lack imagination!)

How can I set a real (wall clock) time limit on script execution instead, which would in general be more useful?